# Select item from foreach on prestashop tpl file

Tags: foreach, task-parallel-library, prestashop

I use this code in the product.tpl file to show product categories:

```
{foreach from=Product::getProductCategoriesFull($product.id_product) item=cat}
                
    <a href="{$link->getCategoryLink({$cat.id_category})}" title="{$cat.name}">{$cat.name}</a>, 
   
{/foreach}
```

The result is similar to this:
Name: Lifts, Machines, Gearless,

The question is:
How can I choose what element I want to show (Lifts only, Machines only or Gearless only)??

I need to show one element from the foreach element position.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass to your TPL only the category you want to display (calculation should be done in PHP file, not Smarty).

If you wanna go the dirty awy you can just

```
{break}
```

after first element display,
or if you want to display a certain category based on its name
just edit your code to something like :

```
{foreach from=Product::getProductCategoriesFull($product.id_product) item=cat}
{if $cat.name == "Lifts"}            
<a href="{$link->getCategoryLink({$cat.id_category})}" title="{$cat.name}">{$cat.name}</a>    
{/if}
{/foreach}
```

Comment: Sorry but this is not a solution in this case.
I need to show the second or third element.
If I write the {break} command it only appears the first element
And i cant filter by category because i have more than 200 categories.
Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a if statement?

```
{foreach from=Product::getProductCategoriesFull($product.id_product) item=cat}
    {if $cat.name == 'Machines'}
        <a href="{$link->getCategoryLink({$cat.id_category})}" title="{$cat.name}">{$cat.name}</a>, 
    {/if}
{/foreach}
```

Comment: But i dont know what is the third element on all products, so I need 400 lines of code? I want to display only middle and last names

Answer (score 0):

```
{assign var="loop_middle" value=Product::getProductCategoriesFull($product.id_product)|@count/2}
{foreach from=Product::getProductCategoriesFull($product.id_product) item=cat name=foo}
    {if $smarty.foreach.foo.last || $smarty.foreach.foo.iteration == $loop_middle|ceil}
        <a href="{$link->getCategoryLink({$cat.id_category})}" title="{$cat.name}">{$cat.name}</a>
    {/if}
{/foreach}
```

This will let you display last element of your array (last category):

```
$smarty.foreach.foo.last
```

This will let you display middle element of your array (middle category):

```
$smarty.foreach.foo.iteration == $loop_middle|ceil
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i put this code for last: